# Swagger ignoring @Schema annotation for write only fields

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui, lombok

The POST API takes a payload with couple of fields where one of them is a write only field. The class has *lombok* @Data annotation to generate setters/getters and the write only field is annotated with *@Getter(AccessLevel.NONE)*. Since lombok is used, the fields are annotated with @Schema with proper description.

```
@Data
public class Query {

    @Schema(description = "List of filter conditions separated by comma.")
    private String filter;

    @Schema(description = "Desired page number (starting from 1).")
    @Getter(AccessLevel.NONE)
    private int page;

    // other fields
}
```

Unfortunately, the given description is ignored by Swagger, and Swagger UI is showing "writeOnly: true" instead of the description mentioned in the @Schema annotation of the field.

[image]

I tried the solution mentioned [here](https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-openapi/issues/398) by adding *lombok.config* with below line, but no luck.

```
lombok.copyableAnnotations += io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.media.Schema
```

However, if I add an explicit setter method with @Schema annotation (instead of mentioning at field level), it is getting honoured and Swagger generates the documentation as expected.

```
@Data
public class Query {

    @Schema(description = "List of filter conditions separated by comma.")
    private String filter;

    @Getter(AccessLevel.NONE)
    private int page;

    // other fields

    @Schema(description = "Desired page number (starting from 1).")
    public void setPage(int page){
        this.page = page;
    }
}
```

[image]

I am wondering, (a) why lombok is not copying the @Schema to the setter method? (b) why Swagger generating the documentation with hardcoded "writeOnly: true"?